# Error which halts program

Tags: error

This is an error message which stops the program. I did a complete delete and reinstall and the problem followed.
This is a windows 10, 2.8,  running on a Lenovo yoga 730 with 8 meg ram.
I also tried installling 2.81

Report error
Traceback (most recent call list)
File “C:\blender\blender2.80\2.80\scrips\bl_operators\wm.py”,line525,in execute value =                 context_path_validate(context, data_path)
File “C:\blender\blender2.80\2.80\scrips\bl_operators\wm.py”,line85,in execute value =                 context_path_validate.%s” % data_path(context, data_path) if data_path else Ellipsis
    File “,line1,
    AttributeError: SpaceError’
   Location :-1

Comment: try running from the command line with `blender.exe --factory-startup` to stop it loading any existing config files.

Comment: I am not familiar with running programs from the command line. What is the actual input after c:\> ?

Comment: I tried and ran blender from the run/command box and it ran correctly but did not save the settings when I closed and re-ran the program. I'm not quite sure how to find and delete the preferences file you are referring to. Can you be a little clearer what the name of the file is and where to find it?

Comment: once you have blender running you can go into preferences and the little hamburger menu has the option to save preferences.